# ComboBox keeps old values while displaying new ones

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

So, it's been 4 hours since I started struggling here.

See, I've got this comboBox and it's bound to a `List<>`, - loads up like it's supposed to; but here I've also got a `textBox` which is supposed to contain text for filter criteria of the `List<>`. Goes nice, packs all the filtered items into a new list, the comboBox displays it... But when I choose to pick an item from it, i.e. a comboBox.Item, it returns the items from the first `list`. Yes, the first list, displaying the values from the filtered `list`; those values are class objects I'm packing into a `dataGridView` later on.

Here's the `TextChanged`:

```
    private void textBox4_TextChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IEnumerable<artikal> filtered =
            from artikal in art
            where artikal.naziv.ToUpper().Contains(textBox4.Text.ToUpper()) || artikal.plu.Contains(textBox4.Text) || artikal.barkod.Contains(textBox4.Text)
            select artikal;
        comboBox1.DataSource = null;
        comboBox1.Items.Clear();
        List<artikal> filter = filtered.ToList<artikal>();
        comboBox1.DataSource = filter;
```

and here's the class, I mean, if it's this important, but I'm not convinced it is:

```
public class artikal
    {
        public string plu { get; set; }
        public string naziv { get; set; }
        public string kolicina { get; set; }
        public string nabavnaCena { get; set; }
        public string prodajnaCnea { get; set; }
        public string barkod { get; set; }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return plu + " " + naziv;
        }
    }
```

This `art` list is a global list defined above all else *in the world*. Here is how I populate the gridview:

```
public partial class NabavkaFrm : Form
{
    #region some stuff lying here

    List<item> art = new List<item>();
    // other code
    row.Cells[0].Value = art[comboBox1.SelectedIndex].plu;
    row.Cells[1].Value = art[comboBox1.SelectedIndex].naziv;
}
```

So, yeah, any suggestions? And good time o' the day to everyone passing by :D

Comment: Do you only want "boys" to answer your question? If not, remove that and welcome to 2018.

Comment: okok, sorry, never again, I guess :D

Comment: Read about Refresh() and ResetBindings()

Comment: Are you sure? How do you know the item is from the previous list?

Comment: Well, see, this list is parsed from a file into the 'art' list of objects. Then, what I did is that I put a button to throw the selected item into a dataGridView just below the other controls; instead of putting the selected filtered item it puts, e.g. the very first item. Let me try to explain: if the first and second items are "one" and "two" respectively, after filtering "six" and "seven" are on their place, but whenever I try to select the "six", it throws the "one" into the dataGridView, so the "seven" throws "two". Also, thank you all for the replies.

Comment: I've tried tons of stuff here, like trashing memory with "aux" lists, setting bindingSources and updating them and nothing, literally nothing ever helped, I'd either break the code down, or achieve the same old stuff I described in the question.

Comment: Unless you provide some runnable code hat reproduces your proble, it will be hard to help you.

Comment: I am pretty confident the issue is not in the code you have posted. The issue is where you get the selected item and display it in the gridview. To test, instead of displaying in a gridview, show the selected item in a message box and see what you get.

Comment: Well, I must have asked it wrong, then. The data from the list is displayed in a comboBox and after this linq query it's updated, but the selected items are the old ones yet. The complete form code's in the answer, not to make the question a trashload of text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment, the issue is not in the code where you filter the items. It cannot be. The issue is right here:

```
row.Cells[0].Value = art[comboBox1.SelectedIndex].plu;
row.Cells[1].Value = art[comboBox1.SelectedIndex].naziv;
```

and because `art` is the class level field, if the item from the combobox is 0, it will always show item at index 0 in `art`. You do not want this. You want to show item at index 0 from your filtered list but that list keeps changing. Sometimes item at index 0 is one thing, whilst another thing another time.

Do it like this instead:

```
var selectedItem = (comboBox1.SelectedValue as item);
row.Cells[0].Value = selectedItem.plu;
```